# Calculating median with three conditions to aggregate a large amount of data

Tags: excel, excel-formula, worksheet-function, median

Looking for some help here at aggregating more than 60,000 data points (a fish telemetry study).  I need to calculate the median of acceleration values by individual fish, date, and hour.  For example, I want to calculate the median for a fish moving from 2:00-2:59PM on June 1.

```
+--------+----------+-------+-------+------+-------+------+-------+-----------+-------------+
|  Date  |   Time   | Month | Diel  |  ID  | Accel |  TL  | Temp  | TempGroup | Behav_group |
+--------+----------+-------+-------+------+-------+------+-------+-----------+-------------+
| 6/1/10 | 01:25:00 |     6 | night | 2084 | 0.94  | 67.5 | 22.81 | High      | Non-angled  |
| 6/1/10 | 01:36:00 |     6 | night | 2084 | 0.75  | 67.5 | 22.81 | High      | Non-angled  |
| 6/1/10 | 02:06:00 |     6 | night | 2084 | 0.75  | 67.5 | 22.65 | High      | Non-angled  |
| 6/1/10 | 02:09:00 |     6 | night | 2084 | 0.57  | 67.5 | 22.65 | High      | Non-angled  |
| 6/1/10 | 03:36:00 |     6 | night | 2084 | 0.75  | 67.5 | 22.59 | High      | Non-angled  |
| 6/1/10 | 03:43:00 |     6 | night | 2084 | 0.57  | 67.5 | 22.59 | High      | Non-angled  |
| 6/1/10 | 03:49:00 |     6 | night | 2084 | 0.57  | 67.5 | 22.59 | High      | Non-angled  |
| 6/1/10 | 03:51:00 |     6 | night | 2084 | 0.57  | 67.5 | 22.59 | High      | Non-angled  |
+--------+----------+-------+-------+------+-------+------+-------+-----------+-------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest adding a column (say `hr`) to your data (containing something like `=HOUR(B2)` copied down to suit) and pivoting your data with `ID`, `Date`, `hr` and `Time` for ROWS and Sum of `Accel` for VALUES. Then copy the pivot table (in Tabular format, without Grand Totals) and Paste Special, Values. On the copy, apply Subtotal At each change in: `hr`, Use function: Average, Add subtotal to: `Sum of Accel` then select the `Sum of Accel` column and replace `SUBTOTAL(1,` with `MEDIAN(`. Change `Average` to `Median` if required.